# Asymptotic behaviour of the fractional part

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Let $f(x)= x (1+[x]-x), \; x\in I\!\!R.$ It is well known (see for example : ARTURAS DUBICKAS, 2006 $\;\&\; $ 2009) that for some irrational numbers $\xi, $ we have 
$\xi\sqrt{n!}-[\xi\sqrt{n!}] \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}-1},\; n\ge1. $ $([x]$ indicates the integer part of $x$). It follows from this inequality that :
$$
f(\xi \sqrt{n!}) \to +\infty, \; as \; \; n \; \to+\infty.
$$

My question is : Do we have $f(\sqrt{n!}) \to +\infty, \; as \; \; n \; \to+\infty?
$

Answer (score 0):

This seems very likely to be true, although I don't know if it can be proved.
If we take a sequence $X_n = m_n + T_n$ where $m_n$ is a given increasing sequence
of positive integers and $T_n$ are independent random variables with uniform distribution in $[0,1]$, then for any positive constant $k$, $\mathbb P(f(X_n) > k) > k/m_n$, so if $\sum_n 1/m_n < \infty$, almost surely $f(X_n) > k$ for all but finitely many $n$ and thus $f(X_n) \to +\infty$.  Of course $\sum_n 1/\sqrt{n!}$ does converge rapidly.  In your case the sequence is deterministic rather than random, but I would be surprised if its behaviour in this respect was much different from a random sequence.